# Complex generating function for Legendre polynomials

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, generating-functions, orthogonal-polynomials, legendre-polynomials

I want to clarify, does the series
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} P_n(x) e^{int} \qquad (1) $$
converge? I know that for all complex $z$, such that $|z|<1$, we have formula
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} P_n(x) z^n = g(x,z) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2xz+z^2}} . \qquad (2) $$
But function $g(x,z)$ has singularities on circle $|z|=1$ and it seems that expression $(2)$ is not applicable in my case $(1)$.

Comment: But the singularities of $g(x,z)$ depend on $x$? Why do you say they're on the circle $|z|=1$? Do you have a particular $x$ in mind?

Comment: @joriki, I mean that for every $x \in [-1,1]$ singularities of $g(x,z)$ belong to circle $|z|=1$.